# An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E\CoffeShop\node_modules' See "C:\aangular-errors.log" for further details

Tags: angular

An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\Angular_April2021\Angular*node_modules*'See "C:\Users\Srisylam\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-ul0h3k\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove slash before /node in below like:

"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css".

Answer (score 0):

For npm install bootstrap@3
Not working "./node_module/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

This works %
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
And also use the above cmd npm install bootstrap@(ur version) will work